# Liferay corrupted arabic, chinese and cyrillic symbols in webcontent and page name

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I have a problem because when I try to save a text(webcontent or page name) in chinese or arabic symbols, push save and the value that I get is always the same: ????....

I tested that is not a problem of DB because if I introduce the arabic value directly in DB, Liferay shows the text in arabic correctly. So no problem of charset , no problem UFT-8.  Liferay sends to database "????" values, but I don´t know why. Anybody could help me!! I'm desperate... :-S

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Well, you definitely have an encoding issue somewhere in the chain. Sticking some data in an encoding that Liferay doesn't write into the database won't help you find the root cause - and writing to the database is recipe for desaster. Don't do this.

Checklist (probably not complete):

- Database must store data in UTF-8 (give us your database schema creation command, and the database)
- Database driver must support & be configured to connect through UTF-8
- JVM must default to UTF-8 file encoding (e.g. for tomcat `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8`)
- HTTP Request for entering content must specify the correct encoding. If you have any proxy between your appserver and the browser, it must handle the encoding correctly.

However, you don't give quite enough information to give you hints: Configuration options on various affected levels (as I've given) would help. An overview over your system architecture as well.